# Reverse GeoCoding connection issues

Tags: r, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to do reversegeocoding on a large dataset. I'm using `RJSONIO` package and using Google map API to get the location of the given lat-lon in the dataset. After 100 or 150 successful displaying location information it is showing:

```
Warning message - "In readLines(con) : cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (null)'"
```

and:

```
Error : "Error in fromJSON(paste(readLines(con), collapse = "")) :
  error in evaluating the argument 'content' in selecting a method for function 'fromJSON': Error in readLines(con) : cannot open the connection"

 location<-function(latlng){
 latlngStr <-  gsub(' ','%20', paste(latlng, collapse=","))
 library("RJSONIO") #Load Library
 #Open Connection
 connectStr <- paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&latlng=',latlngStr, sep="")
 con <- url(connectStr)
 data.json <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(con), collapse=""))
 close(con)
 data.json <- unlist(data.json)
 if(data.json["status"]=="OK")
   address <- data.json["results.formatted_address"]
   print (address)
 }
```

What are the probable reasons and how to fix the issue?

I'm using R version 3.2.1 and Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Are there any limits set to the number of queries one can perform in a given time period?

Comment: For that issue I have already  set a wait function that is invoked after each query and halts the execution for 5 seconds, still same problem remains.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-July/430877.html)

Comment: You should use `ggmap::revgeocode` (it calls google's api) and google
will rate-limit you. There are also packages to use HERE maps
geo/revgeo lookups
http://blog.corynissen.com/2014/10/making-r-package-to-use-here-geocode-api.html
and the geocode package has `GNfindNearestAddres`s, so tons of options
to choose from. And, you now have [nominatim](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim). Proper bulk geocoding is going to cost you $ one way or another (either up front for API, AWS server farm or legal fees/fines/damages).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're hitting usage limits, there are always limits:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Besides these, there are also limitations to what you can (rightfully) use the API responses for, specially around storing those responses:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/policies
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions
(see 10.5.d in particular)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar error accessing the google API with ggmap functions. If you're under rate limit, likely the server is just failing to respond (as any server can do sometimes and you're more likely to encounter the more data you pull).

If you don't have any error handling in your code for what to do when the server doesn't respond, you're script will break with an error message. The simple solution is to build in some error handling by re-pinging the API a few times if it returns an error (e.g., if it doesn't work, try again).

Here is what has fixed it in my scripts:

```
attempt = 1 #start attempt counter

while(attempt != 20) #repeat the API request for up to 20 times
{
  #use try to test for whether or not your API function returns error
  dat.test <- try(PASTE YOUR FUNCTION THAT IS CALLING THE API INTO HERE) 

  if(is(dat.test, 'try-error')) #check if try returned error when pinging the API
  {
    #do these things if an error is returned
    #if there is an error, after completing these items the while loop will continue to the next attempt to reach the API 
    Sys.sleep(1) #wait 1 second
    warning("reattempting google api fetch...") #warn the user
    attempt <- attempt + 1 #update the attempt counter
  } else break #exit the while loop if no error returned (API returned data successfully))
}
```